# Contagem regressiva que se renova à meia noite utilizando javascript puro

Tags: javascript

> Como fazer para mostrar as horas e minutos que faltam para as 00:00 horas (meia-noite) ?

#### Exemplo:

> Tenho um site de vendas no qual quero colocar uma contagem regressiva que diz o tempo restante para a meia noite, o qual quando der meia noite, apareça 23h 59m 59s.

Vai ser uma espécie de propaganda, do tipo, "Corre! Faltam só XX h XX m XX s"

Se a pessoa tiver por exemplo às 20:31, vai mostrar 3h 29m 00s.

E assim sussecivamente....

Vi esse exemplo, porém não tive a capacidade de fazê-lo funcionar: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq

Só que quero algo simples, apenas um texto "XXh XXm XXs". Nada de CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```js
function calculateHMSleft()
{
 var now = new Date();
 var hoursleft = 23-now.getHours();
 var minutesleft = 59-now.getMinutes();
 var secondsleft = 59-now.getSeconds();
 if(minutesleft<10) minutesleft = "0"+minutesleft;
 if(secondsleft<10) secondsleft = "0"+secondsleft;
 document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = hoursleft+":"+minutesleft+":"+secondsleft;
}
calculateHMSleft();
setInterval(calculateHMSleft, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="count"></div>
```

Resposta [adaptada a partir daqui](http://shanelabs.com/blog/2011/12/08/end-of-the-day-countdown-in-javascript/)

Comment: É isso aí, só editei aqui essa parte hoursleft+"h "+minutesleft+"m "+secondsleft+"s"; pra ficar como queria! Resposta perfeita! Você é fera! ;)

Comment: Eu que agradeço!!! :D

Comment: Estava a fazer uma versão à mão, que precisava de mais ajustes. Apaguei. A tua resposta foi mais rápida e ficou bem parecida com esta: http://shanelabs.com/blog/2011/12/08/end-of-the-day-countdown-in-javascript/ Se fôr essa mesmo é bom colocares referências... `+1`

Comment: Foi sim com algumas adpações para javascript @Sergio. É verdade, colocada a referência